# Set File Permissions on aosp

Tags: android, android-source

I need to set new permissions on some files in aosp. I am using FileUtils.setPermissions(). But when I make a check using FileUtils.getPermissions I get the same permissions always as "33188" and I want it to be 0777.

How can I do it. BTW I am doin this operation in PacakageManagerService.java.

Answer (score 1):

You should at first build needed value that should be passed to `FileUtils.setPermission`. For  instance, in your case code can be the following:

```
int perm = FileUtils.S_IRWXU|FileUtils.S_IRWXG|FileUtils.S_IRWXO;
FileUtils.setPermissions(fileName, perm, ...);
```